# I wanted to search for Photos by the Dimensions in Pixel Size but - Expected end of line, etc. but found identifier... what should I do?

Tags: python, css, ios, macos, applescript

I honestly have no idea what I'm doing but I wanted to run this script I found on the internet (https://discussions.apple.com/docs/DOC-11621 ) because I'm running low on cloud storage and wanted to find out which photos, videos, media of mine were taking up the most space so I could delete what was really necessary. All of this off of my MacBook Air. Unfortunately, when plugging in the script into **AppleScript** I kept on coming across this;

> **Syntax error:**  Expected end of line, etc. but found identifier.

what should i do!!!!

Comment: please add the script instead of a link to the script

Comment: At least tell us what line you get the error on, please...